# How do I fix invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 79)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord announcement bot:

However, I keep receiving an error: [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIncR.png)

What I am trying to accomplish is to make a announcement bot so when a user in your channel does `.announce <text>` it sends an embed to a specific channel like this: https://prnt.sc/rgw4yc

````
async def announce(ctx, message : str):
    try:
        for chan in channels:
            try: 
                channel = bot.get_channel(channel id)
                info = discord.Embed(title="New Announcement!", description=str(message), color=0xFFFFFF)
                await channel.send(embed=info)

                try: 
                    except Exception as e:
                    await ctx.send(e)
                    await ctx.send("Error: " + str(chan))

                 except Exception as e:
                 await ctx.send(e) ```
````

Comment: You have an `except Exception as e:` that doesn't indent the block under it. Actually, you do that *twice*. And one of your `except`s isn't aligned with a `try`.

Comment: (Repeating for emphasis: They `except` has to be **aligned with** the `try`, **NOT indented under** it).

Comment: I did so now I am getting this error: https://prnt.sc/rgxq29

Comment: You need to figure out which `try` goes with which `except`. Also you only have two `except`s and three `try`s, so something is wrong there as well. Try to think more carefully about your intended logic. Try to explain the entire process in plain English; or draw a flowchart; or something.

Comment: @Sheogorathaf, [screenshots are not acceptable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122). If you don't have an answer yet, it's appropriate to [edit] the question; if you do, the appropriate action is to ask a new question.

Comment: @Sheogorathaf, ...beyond that, you need to have the *body* of your `try` block *before* the `except` block; you can't just go straight from the try to the except with no body.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIncR.png)

The error is in following section of the code

```
try: 
                    except Exception as e:
                    await ctx.send(e)
                    await ctx.send("Error: " + str(chan))
```

You cannot use except within try loop. Logic flows as 
try performing an action if fails raise exception this way you prevent whole code from failing

example

```
try:
       r=requests.get(some_url)
 except:
       print("Request Failed")
```

In above example if variable `some_url` has wrong URL or site is down it will print Request failed and continue with the remainder of the code.